# Update recycler view when new data is added

Tags: java, android

Im having trouble updating my recylcer view when i add new data to the list. The list only updates when i restart my app.
I've tried using Adapter.notifyItemChanged(array.size()-1) in my "listAktinovsti" function but didnt work, i have also tried adding notifyitemchanged to my alterdialog on click function and that also didnt work. Here's my code so far. i will post my adapter class if its needed.

**This is my fragment class.**

```
public class TodoFragment extends Fragment {
    private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    AppDatabase db;
    ToDoRecyclerViewAdapter mmAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public TodoFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todo_list, container, false);
        final FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        openDB();

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                View popupView = li.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
                final EditText editText = popupView.findViewById(R.id.userInput);
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                adb.setView(popupView);

                adb.setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Dodaj", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                String naziv = editText.getText().toString();
                                Aktivnost_ ak = new Aktivnost_(naziv, null,0,null);
                                dodajAktivnost(ak);

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Prekliči", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.cancel();
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Preklical sem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = adb.create();
                alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        mmAdapter = new ToDoRecyclerViewAdapter(listAktivnosti(),mListener);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mmAdapter);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
       void onListFragmentInteraction(Aktivnost_ item);
    }

    public void dodajAktivnost(Aktivnost_ ak) {
        boolean dodaj = db.addRow(ak);
        if(dodaj) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "dodano v bazo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "nope", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void openDB() {
        db = new AppDatabase(getContext());
        db.open();
    }

    public List<Aktivnost_> listAktivnosti() {
        openDB();
        ArrayList<Aktivnost_> array = new ArrayList<>();
        Aktivnost_ ak;
        Cursor cursor = db.getAllRows();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            ak = new Aktivnost_();
            ak.setId_(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            ak.setNaziv(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("naziv")));
            ak.setDatum(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("datum")));
            ak.setFk_projekt(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("fk_projekt")));
            ak.setUdeleženci(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("udelezenci")));
            array.add(ak);
        }
        return array;
    }

}
```

Comment: When you add NEW data call notifyDataSetChanged() or notifyItemInserted(int position)

Comment: I add new data in this section of the code "Aktivnost_ ak = new Aktivnost_(naziv, null,0,null); dodajAktivnost(ak); but i already tried calling the notifydatasetchanged fucntion from there but it didnt work. i've have also tried calling it from my function "dodajAktivnost" where i add data to sqllite again didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code it is not clear to me where exactly you do add the new item. If it is in the onClick() of the positive button:

1. remove this declaration `ArrayList<Aktivnost_> array = new ArrayList<>();` from `listAktivnosti` and put it after the header of the `public class TodoFragment extends Fragment {`
2. after adding the item to the db, add the item to `array` and call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: i add new data in my "dodajAktivnost" function,yes. Tried that didnt work.

Comment: Did you add the item to the array?

Comment: That array has nothing to do with adding data to the DB. I only store values that i get FROM the database in that array. So im kinda confused here, sorry.

Comment: I know the array has nothing to do with adding data to the DB but it has everything to do with showing the data in your recyclerview.

Comment: I have added the item to the array but it didnt work. But just in case i am misunderstadning this could you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: This array holds the data displayed in the recyclerview. After every change you make in the db you must make the corresponding change in the array and call the necessary notifySomething() for your adapter. So this array needs to be visible everywhere in your fragment and not local in List<Aktivnost_> listAktivnosti()

Comment: Ok, made the array visible to the whole fragment and called notify...in my "dodajAktivnosti" function where i  add new data, sadly it didnt work. maybe im missing something super simple here would you mind showing me what you mean in code?

Comment: Just before mmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); (line 40) insert your new data in the array: array.add(ak);

Comment: omg it worked :) thank you, feel kinda embarrassed i missed this.

Answer (score 0):

After you changed your data, add this code right after when you changed your data:
yourAdapterName.notifyDataSetChanged()

This should work for you.

Comment: I tried adding notifyDataSetChanged right after i add new data but didnt work